# Floating Point Bug in OpenCL via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, floating-point, kernel, opencl

I found a problem with floating point arithmetic in OpenCL. This is my kernel:

```
__kernel void MyKernel(__global const float4* _pInput, __global float4* _pOutput)
{
    int IndexOfRow      = get_global_id(0);
    int NumberOfRows    = get_global_size(0);
    int IndexOfColumn   = get_global_id(1);
    int NumberOfColumns = get_global_size(1);

    ...

   _pOutput[0] = 1.9f * 100.0f; // constant float return value
}
```

After the kernel execution and download of the output buffer the result is always 100 on different clients using an ssh connection. If I execute the program locally the result is 190. It seems that the digits after the decimal point are cut off.

The operating system is a Open Suse Linux with AMD OpenCL 1.2.

What's the problem?

Comment: If you make index different for each thread, it will be 190.0 or 189.999. You have made it zero and that can be undefined behaviour while all threads race for a single element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the solution. It depends on your ENV setting for LANG. It has to be en_US.UTF-8. You can check it with `env|grep LANG`.

That’s probably a JIT compiler bug. In Germany floating points are written with an „,“ instead of „.“.